# Using Reg_ex on Spark Data Frame in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following log

```
2015-07-22T09:00:28.019143Z,marketpalce-shop,263.242.248.130:54635,10.0.6.158:80,0.000022,0.026109,0.00002,200,200,0,699,GET https://prjbfekbf.com:443/ship/authresponse?code=f2405b05-e2ee-4b0d-8f6a-9fed0fcfe2e0&state=null HTTP/1.1,Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,TLSv1.2
```

This is a data frame in my spark dataset. I am looking to extract the Time stamp, Ip address, Browser Type and Device type from this log.

Spark dataframe unlike pandas dataframe has confusing documentation on how to extract these. I tried almost all solutions on SO. Please help to with any external reference or idea on how to do this.

Please don't mark this as duplicate seeing ip and reg-ex words. Though these are common, it was not done for scala and spark dataframe before.

Comment: expected output in dataframe?

Comment: Can you add some of the things you have tried to the quesiton? As it is right now it's not very clear what you want to do. Have you tried with [regexp_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#regexp_extract(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20java.lang.String,%20int))?

Comment: Yes, i tried regexp_extract and it didnt work out for some strange reason. I also tried Transformer thing available in MLlib. Apart from these, I tried some string indexing using filter @Shaido

Comment: @TahaNaqvi Yes, I need the output in DataFrame to process it further.

Comment: i meant to say sample dataframe..what do u want to see in the resultant dataframe after extracting the above mentioned values..

Comment: @TahaNaqvi I want ip without that PORT_NAME, just time instead of whole time stamp, just the browser name instead of that whole big thing.